# one api request not working for ngrok (while others do)

Tags: localhost, webhooks, ngrok

I set up ngrok at port 8888 and I got it running. My app is accessible via the provided url (I added it as vhost in the apache config) and everything seems to run smooth. My app consumes an api that is also in my localhost, all the requests work except one (when accessing via ngrok). The request that doesn't work is the one to authenticate the user. Returns 401 Unauthorized. My guess is that ngrok request has different headers and something doesn't quite work in the api but I don't know what. Also, all the other requests do work. Maybe it's not even that... any ideas?

Here are the reuqest headers when accessing the ngrok url and the localhost url:

ngrok url

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type    application/json
Cookie  _ga=GA1.2.372684863.1425176717 
Host    23f9aa37.ngrok.com
PHP_AUTH_PW testing
PHP_AUTH_USER   testing
Referer http://23f9aa37.ngrok.com/multikanban/app/login
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:36.0)   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

localhost request

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type    application/json
Cookie  SQLiteManager_currentLangue=2;   PHPSESSID=e500334d5e6203cd5242be050f1eab3a
Host    localhost:8888
PHP_AUTH_PW testing
PHP_AUTH_USER   testing
Referer http://localhost:8888/multikanban/app/login
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```